# Matlab performance in creating an array of nested objects

Tags: performance, matlab

Using Matlab 2010b Service Pack 1. We are having a performance issue when creating an array of 1000 objects.

The array is obj.MyClassArray

The objects are of class

```
classdef MyClass < handle
properties
    prop1
    prop2
    prop3
    nameValueContainerMap % a container.Map(name, MySeriesObject)
end
```

The map class is

```
classdef MySeries < handle
properties
    dates
    values % a cell containing n doubles
end
```

The cell consists of an array of doubles.

We are pre-allocating memory by initialising obj.MyClassArray with 1000 copies of a fully populated object of MyClass, using repmat.

However, we are still finding a performance issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show a working example of your code, and make sure to include the profiling results. Without looking at any code I can only wonder whether you really need a class, or perhaps you can simply use a struct for example. I would not be surprised if that could reduce some overhead.

Comment: How are the constructors for `MyClass` and `MySeries` implemented?